# TestFairy not reporting crashes

Tags: ios, testfairy

It was working for a moment and it suddenly stopped working.

So, the integration is fine, I guess. The version is 1.7.9

Now, what I get is videos and logs for the entire sessions except when the app crashes the video ends and there is no flag of crash in dashboard..
Have anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestFairy causes delay during app launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043057/testfairy-causes-delay-during-app-launch)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are initializing another crash handler (eg, HockeyApp or Crashlytics) after calling [TestFairy begin]? Most crash handlers don't pass the call after catching the exception, so only the last handler to be initialized will actually get the callback. TestFairy writes a log, and it should also appear in the session overview itself (in the timeline widget.) Hope this helps!

Comment: Exceptions are only one type of crashes. all other crashes are intercepted using Signal Handlers (and/or Mach Exceptions), and there can only be one of those and they can not be forwarded. So forwarding exceptions would only be one reason for this not working.

Comment: @gilm, I made sure testfairy is the last thing called in `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions ` method. However nothing changed..