# TestFairy causes delay during app launch

Tags: ios, testfairy

I was using TestFairy for quite a time now, and suddenly it started slowing up the app launch.

I get this error when testFairy is initialised in `appdelegate`:

```
*** error reading settings archive file: <ISRootSettings: /Users/Zakaria/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/17557909-146C-4075-926F-D9BFD334E120/data/Containers/Data/Application/AA791370-AED4-4CA6-A166-E984A379CAB2/Documents/{app_bundle}/ISRootSettings_10.plist>
```

And then:

```
TestFairy: Initializing SDK version 1.7.8 
TestFairy: Session started successfully
TestFairy is no longer the default crash handler
```

And by the way, it doesn't record crash reports anymore :(

Comment: `TestFairy is no longer the default crash handler` already tells you that it won't report any crashes, most likely because you added another framework that collects crashes. There can only be one. For the test: did you ask their support for help?

Comment: @kerni, I moved the testFairy initialisation to the end of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, now I'm not getting the `TestFairy is no longer the default crash handler`. However crashes are not reported.. No I didn't I have a free account, so I don't expect getting any help from them.

Answer (score 0):

The message `TestFairy is no longer the default crash handler` only appears if another crash handler is the default. Crashlytics and HockeyApp crash handlers don't pass the call to the next in chain, so if they are initialized after TestFairy, they will catch the exception and not pass it onwards.

About the delay. Do you have more information? Such as, how slow it suddenly is now? (in milliseconds).

Comment: I moved the testFairy initialisation to the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, now I'm not getting the TestFairy is no longer the default crash handler. However crashes are not reported.. 
About the delay, it depends. Sometimes the app stops is stuck in splash screen forever and the log shows it's on testFairy initialisation phase.